# Is it possible to add undirected and directed edges to a graph object in networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I'm working on implementing an algorithm to determine the graphical structure of a dataset. The dataset could have undirected or directed edges between variables. I could create my own graph object in Python, but I was curious if Networkx has this capability. From what I've seen, Networkx only has a Graph object (only undirected edges) and a DiGraph object (for directed edges only). Is there a way to include directed edges in a undirected graph in Networkx and/or vice versa?

Comment: Hrm... is there a difference between undirected edges and bi-directional edges?

Comment: @ScottBoston Good question. I think technically there is a difference, but for the purposes of my algorithm, I think it'd be alright to represent the undirected edges with bidirected edges (the algorithm doesn't take into account bidrectionality).

Comment: Then go for bidirectional edges, it will be the easiest formalism to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston and m.raynal . Out of curiosity, is there a way to handle the difference between undirected and bi-directional edges in Networkx?

Comment: Honestly I do not know (I never worked with `networkx`). The usual term to refer to graphs which are both directed and undirected is `mixed graph` (even if [the definition seems to be foggy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55903/what-is-a-mixed-graph)). So I'd suggest you to look for that term in `networkx`, but I have the feeling that it's a rare enough object so very few libraries do actually implement them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`networkx` has no mixed graph handling. There were [discussions about it](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1168), but the implementation had an impact on the whole library, so it was suspended. As I know, `graph-tool` and `igraph` has no this functionality too. If you are not satisfied by bidirected edges as undirected, I am afraid you should not use Python libraries, because it is impossible to have both directed and undirected edges in the most popular Python graph libraries: `networkx`, `graph-tool` and `igraph`.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating my own graph class to handle both.