# From Matrix to Graph (directed and undirected) using networkx

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

Starting from the following bumpy matrix I would like to create a graph using the python library Networkx

```
matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
        [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Where:

- 0 means that the node is NOT connected to another node
- 1 means that the node is connected to another node
- 2 means that the node has an outgoing arrow to another node (e.g., 1 --> 6)

The problem is that I'm able to draw directed or undirected graph, but not a mix of both.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can we assume that `1` means a bidirectional connection between two nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#libraries
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

#input
X = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
        [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])


G = nx.DiGraph(X>0)
nx.draw_kamada_kawai(G, with_labels=True)
```

[image: graph]

In this way you have that undirected edges are bidirectional connection. I think there is not another way to implement your graph in `networkx` because the mixed graph are not allowed, as mentioned here:

-[Is it possible to add undirected and directed edges to a graph object in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496703/is-it-possible-to-add-undirected-and-directed-edges-to-a-graph-object-in-network)

-[MixedGraph and MixedMultiGraph](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1168)

The only other solution I can imagine is to build a directed graph and separately an undirected graph, but it obliviously depends on what is your goal and on what the graph is to be used for.